# python selenium scrape multi page table

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The purpose of this code is to scrape a multipage table of data from a certain URL. And it worked fine just for the first row no more.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


class DataEngine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = 'https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/house-price-index-147'
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r"D:\Projects\Tutorial\Driver\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe")

    def title(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        title = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="leftColumn"]/h1')
        for title in title:
            print(title.text)

    def table(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        while True:
            table = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="historicEvent_372690"]')
            for table in table:
                print(table.text)
```

Comment: Which _multipage table of data_ are you trying to scrape?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure your code scrapes all rows on the page, update the xpath

`//*[@id="historicEvent_372690"]`

to

`//*[contains(@id,"historicEvent_")]`

The xpath you are using currently only reads the first row. The xpath I shared uses the contains keyword that looks for all elements that contain id `historicEvent_`